# Notepad++ Tweaking

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, themes

Is it possible to get Notepad++ to have background themes like other text editors have? I know that you can have syntax highlighting, but I've seen editors like Eclipse and Visual Studio have background colors and such? Is this possible to do with Notepad++?

**UPDATE**

I found that Version 5.6.6 of Notepad++ now has a drop down list of built in themes that can be selected from `Settings > Style Configurator > Select Theme`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Notepad++ has a latest release 5.5.1 has some built in themes you can take advantage of. If you want little bit more customization, you can change the colors of every element in UI as you want.

Quick google search shows that there a vibrant community of TextMate(Mac Editor) has a good themes. http://joyboner.com/60-free-textmate-notepad-styler-themes/ will show you how to convert those themes for notepad++.

From http://joyboner.com/60-free-textmate-notepad-styler-themes/:

> Step 1. Assuming you already have
>   Notepad++ installed, navigate your
>   browser over to the Textmate Theme
>   Directory.
>
> Step 2. Choose a rad looking theme and
>   download it.
>
> Step 3. Fire up Notepad++ and open the
>   .tmTheme file you just downloaded.
>
> Step 4. Select all (Ctrl+A) and copy
>   (Ctrl+C)
>
> Step 5. Now navigate your browser over
>   to the [theme converter page](http://framework.lojcomm.com.br/tmTheme2nppStyler/).
>
> Step 6. Paste what you copied from
>   Notepad++ into the big textbox and
>   click the download button and save the
>   file.
>
> Step 7. In Explorer, navigate to:
>   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\%%USERNAME%%\Application
>   Data\Notepad++\
>
> Step 8. Locate the original styler
>   theme file (stylers.xml) and rename it
>   to something like original.stylers.xml
>
> Step 9. Take the file you downloaded
>   from Step 6 and move it to the
>   location in Step 7.
>
> Step 10. Rename the file you just
>   moved to stylers.xml
>
> Step 11. Close Notepad++ and reopen
>   it.
>
> Step 12. Enjoy your new colors!

Hope this helps.

Comment: This can keep me busy all day. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 4):

You can edit colors in Notepad++ by using the Styler Configurator from the Settings Menu.

Answer (score 2):

Background colors is possible.

Go to Settings->Style Configurator, and set the checkboxes "Enable".

[image: Notepad++ config]

You can [create your themes](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/changeTheme-HOWTO.php) as well, even ones that look like [Textmate](http://joyboner.com/60-free-textmate-notepad-styler-themes/).